# How to make all Time outputs be ISO 8601 in Ruby + Grape API

Tags: ruby, monkeypatching, iso8601, ruby-grape

I've been looking around for the easiest solution to convert all Datetime values to ISO 8601 when sending them to a specific requester from an API. I was able to monkey patch `Time#to_json` with the following:

```
class Time
  def to_json(options = {})
    self.iso8601.to_json
  end
end
```

And require the file in the `before` callback of Grape when params showed the request was coming from the desired location.

Is this the best way to accomplish this? Could I instead be doing something in the `after` callback of Grape to loop through my data and convert the values there? Monkey patching `Time#to_json` gets the job done, but feels funny to me. Though I am new to Ruby.

Comment: Your instincts are good.  Monkey patching classes should only be used as a last resort.  In your case I think it's a bad idea because who knows where else in the program the default behavior might be relied upon -- and if not now, maybe in the future.  You can add this message to individual Time instances if you can figure out which instances need modifying.

Comment: Where are your `Time` instances coming from? What do you use as a backend? Could you create a wrapper (presenter) class for `Time` and use that instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Grape Entity to expose your models? If you're using it then you can define a reusable formatter like this:

```
module ApiHelpers
  extend Grape::API::Helpers

  Grape::Entity.format_with :iso8601 do |date|
    date.iso8601 if date
  end
end
```

Then, you can use this formatter in all your entities:

```
module Entities
  class MyModel < Grape::Entity
    expose :updated_at, format_with: :iso8601
  end

  class AnotherModel < Grape::Entity
    expose :created_at, format_with: :iso8601
  end
end
```

But if you're not using Grape Entity... well, I think you should. :)

PS.: All examples I showed here were extracted from Grape Entity documentation.
https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape-entity

Comment: Hi, not currently using Grape Entity, but I did look at it some. I need more arguments in favor of it, as just solving this problem isn't reason enough to invest the time to transition.

Comment: First off, I think you should always shield your API from possible changes in your Models and vice-versa. Also, remember that what you expose through a Rest API are "Resources" and not Models. In fact, a resource can even be a combination of multiple Models. Entities allow you to define a Resource and reuse it whenever you need it. Using entities, you can exclude fields, create fields that are a combination of others fields. In a nutshell, it gives you flexibility.